# Apache Camel / regex replace characters

Tags: regex, apache-camel

We have a JSON string being returned as result of an oData query.

1. We wish to strip the "@" sign in the tags like

   - @odata.etag
   - msdyn_journaltype@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue
   - msdyn_endtime@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue
   - etc
2. Without touching the email address value like "email": "bob@thebuilder.com".

I read the Apache Camel documentation at http://camel.apache.org/simple.html, I can use

```
${in.body.replace('@', '')}
```

but the email adress will also be stripped.

Of course I can do it in multiple steps, like

```
${in.body.replace('msdyn_journaltype@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue', 'msdyn_journaltypeOData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue')}
```

but this can  be done better, right?
I was thinking the Apache Camel 'regex' function, but am not that well experienced with regex.

Someone who knows the tricks of regex?

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https:\/\/xxx.api.crm4.dynamics.com\/api\/data\/v9.0\/$metadata#bookableresourcebookings(name,msdyn_milestraveled,msdyn_actualarrivaltime,statecode,msdyn_workorder(foc_sapordernumber),Resource(name,foc_sapresourcenumber,email),msdyn_bookableresourcebooking_msdyn_bookingjournal_Booking(msdyn_journaltype,msdyn_name,msdyn_starttime,msdyn_endtime,msdyn_duration,foc_sapstatisticalkeyfigurecod,statecode))",
  "@odata.count": 9,
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.etag": "W\/\"5775823\"",
      "name": "Wartung 2011153  - Wartung - 181 L1205 Stuttgarter Str.\/Aichbr\u00fccke ",
      "msdyn_milestraveled@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "0,00",
      "msdyn_milestraveled": 0,
      "msdyn_actualarrivaltime@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "30.10.2018 08:55",
      "msdyn_actualarrivaltime": "2018-10-30T08:55:00Z",
      "statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Active",
      "statecode": 0,
      "bookableresourcebookingid": "bd90b7e6-18dc-e811-a95a-000d3a29f080",
      "msdyn_workorder": {
        "foc_sapordernumber": "856900132812"
      },
      "Resource": {
        "name": "Bob the Builder",
        "foc_sapresourcenumber": "00290035",
        "email": "bob@thebuilder.com"
      },
      "msdyn_bookableresourcebooking_msdyn_bookingjournal_Booking": [
        {
          "@odata.etag": "W\/\"5775798\"",
          "msdyn_journaltype@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Working Hours",
          "msdyn_journaltype": 690970000,
          "msdyn_name": "Wartung 2011153  - Wartung - 181 L1205 Stuttgarter Str.\/Aichbr\u00fccke ",
          "msdyn_starttime@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "29.10.2018 14:30",
          "msdyn_starttime": "2018-10-29T14:30:00Z",
          "msdyn_endtime@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "29.10.2018 16:00",
          "msdyn_endtime": "2018-10-29T16:00:00Z",
          "msdyn_duration@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "90",
          "msdyn_duration": 90,
          "foc_sapstatisticalkeyfigurecod": "",
          "statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Active",
          "statecode": 0,
          "_msdyn_booking_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Wartung 2011153  - Wartung - 181 L1205 Stuttgarter Str.\/Aichbr\u00fccke ",
          "_msdyn_booking_value": "bd90b7e6-18dc-e811-a95a-000d3a29f080",
          "msdyn_bookingjournalid": "fd340afc-39dc-e811-a95a-000d3a29f080"
        },
        {
          "@odata.etag": "W\/\"5775795\"",
          "msdyn_journaltype@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Travel",
          "msdyn_journaltype": 690970002,
          "msdyn_name": "Test WPLAN ohne Vertragstermine III  - Wartung - Bismarckplatz Ost ",
          "msdyn_starttime@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "29.10.2018 13:32",
          "msdyn_starttime": "2018-10-29T13:32:00Z",
          "msdyn_endtime@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "29.10.2018 14:30",
          "msdyn_endtime": "2018-10-29T14:30:00Z",
          "msdyn_duration@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "58",
          "msdyn_duration": 58,
          "foc_sapstatisticalkeyfigurecod": "",
          "statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Active",
          "statecode": 0,
          "_msdyn_booking_value@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue": "Wartung 2011153  - Wartung - 181 L1205 Stuttgarter Str.\/Aichbr\u00fccke ",
          "_msdyn_booking_value": "bd90b7e6-18dc-e811-a95a-000d3a29f080",
          "msdyn_bookingjournalid": "d52eafbd-42dc-e811-a95a-000d3a29f080"
        }
      ],
      "msdyn_bookableresourcebooking_msdyn_bookingjournal_Booking@odata.nextLink": "https:\/\/xxx.api.crm4.dynamics.com\/api\/data\/v9.0\/bookableresourcebookings(bd90b7e6-18dc-e811-a95a-000d3a29f080)\/msdyn_bookableresourcebooking_msdyn_bookingjournal_Booking?$select=msdyn_journaltype,msdyn_name,msdyn_starttime,msdyn_endtime,msdyn_duration,foc_sapstatisticalkeyfigurecod,statecode"
    }
  ],
  "msdyn_bookableresourcebooking_msdyn_bookingjournal_Booking@odata.nextLink": "https:\/\/xxx.api.crm4.dynamics.com\/api\/data\/v9.0\/bookableresourcebookings(3931de11-f86d-41a8-b483-c9416d20bf0c)\/msdyn_bookableresourcebooking_msdyn_bookingjournal_Booking?$select=msdyn_journaltype,msdyn_name,msdyn_starttime,msdyn_endtime,msdyn_duration,foc_sapstatisticalkeyfigurecod,statecode"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data, I feel you can replace all the `@` that are followed by `OData` assuming there is no email where you have `OData` as domain name. Hence you can use this regex,

```
(?i)@(?=OData)
```

Here `(?i)` ensures match is case insensitive and `(?=OData)` positive look ahead ensures `@` is immediately followed by `OData`

And replace it with empty string.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uj5oTu/1)**

Let me know if this works fine for you.

**Edit: Incorporating `@Link` and `@Id` in addition to `@OData` and also replacing `\/` with `/` globally (and not just name attribute), you can use this regex,**

```
(?i)@(?=(?:OData|link|id)\b)|\\(\/)
```

And replace it with `$1` or `\1` as applicable in your language.

**[Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uj5oTu/2)**

If you don't want to replace `\/` with `/` globally, you can use this regex,

```
(?i)@(?=(?:OData|link|id)\b)
```

And replace it with empty string

And like I said in comment, for replacing `\/` with `/` in just name attribute, you will have to use some programming code.

Comment: Perfect! Let's say theoretically we not only need to replace '@OData' but a second or third element like '@Link' and '@Id', or in the "name" element '\/'  with '/'. Can that be included in the same regex?

Comment: @user2215655: Yes, in addition to `OData` it can additionally be done for `@Link` and `@Id` too in the same regex. And also `\/` can be replaced with `/` if in the same regex then it will replace all and not just the name attribute. For specifically replacing `\/` to `/` in name attribute, it will be a little hard as it will need variable length lookbehind which is usually not available. Let me update my answer for your comment.